# Can I link to a specific time in a video (or add a description for a video with timestamps)?

Tags: hyperlink, video

When a video is uploaded to SharePoint:

- Is there some way to create a link which goes to a specific time in the video?
- Is there some way to attach a description to the video? (Ideally in such way that whenever the description uses a timestamp, it will be clickable and the user would be able to go to a specific point of the video.)

---

To add some context, I am asking this because of teaching and our school uses Microsoft Teams. Recordings of meetings (in my case lectures, recitations, consultations) used to be saved in Microsoft Stream. (The version which they now called Microsoft Stream (Classic). Not too long ago, they announced that [the new version will upload videos to SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/stream/streamnew/new-stream).)

With the old version, I was able to create a link going to a specific time in the video. (See here: [How to get a link to an exact time in a Microsoft Stream video?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/153894)) And I also had a possibility to add a description to each video - and if I used times formatted as 2:00, they were automatically converted to links, so that the students could then go directly to the part of the video which is interesting for them. (This is described, for example, in this tutorial: [Microsoft Stream: editing video details](https://sites.reading.ac.uk/tel-support-for-students/2020/09/08/microsoft-stream-editing-video-details/).)

---

<sup>I wasn't sure whether to ask two separate questions or whether it is ok to have this in a single question. In the end, I opted for a single question - after all if there is some way to create link with a timestamp, then I can simply created a description with the timestamps somewhere else, even if that's not possible directly in SharePoint.</sup>

Comment: I wasn't sure whether I should include the tag ([tag:microsoft-teams]). In my case, the video is uploaded to SharePoint by MS Teams - but I do not think that the way how the video gets there does really matter.

Comment: you should still be able to upload your video to Stream.also, maybe you can ask your Teams admins to change the setting to save videos in Stream instead of SharePoint

Comment: Thanks for you comment @DenisMolodtsov. Yes, that would be possible. (Of course, there is an additional work of uploading the video to the classic version of MS Stream.) Still, it would be nice to know whether something like this is possible also on the new version, which relies on SharePoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store a video in SharePoint Online, then there is no out-of-the-box feature that would allow you to start it from a specific time stamp.

**Ways to deal with it**

- Upload your video to Stream. You have to do it manually, which involves extra steps.
- Upload you video to YouTube or other Video Sharing services. Most of them allow you to start a video from a specific time stamp.
- [Vote for Microsoft to introduce Steam Connector to Flow](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/Microsoft-Stream-Connector/idi-p/572993). This would allow IT professionals upload videos to Stream from SharePoint automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicated from here:  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/173576/260555

---

For the new Stream platform (not Stream "Classic"), appending something similar to the following works for me:

```
&nav=%7B%22playbackOptions%22%3A%7B%22startTimeInSeconds%22%3A999%7D%7D
```

Try replacing the `999` with your time in seconds and appending to your existing Sharepoint-Stream URL.

This can be duplicated by clicking on "Share" and "Embed".  Check and adjust the "Start from" value, and then inspect the embed URL code.

If you are curious about the %-encoded terms, decoding them shows this is a JSON payload provided in the URL:

```
&nav={"playbackOptions":{"startTimeInSeconds":999}}
```